# Convert columns to string in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, type-conversion

I have the following DataFrame from a SQL query:

```
(Pdb) pp total_rows
     ColumnID  RespondentCount
0          -1                2
1  3030096843                1
2  3030096845                1
```

and I pivot it like this:

```py
total_data = total_rows.pivot_table(cols=['ColumnID'])
```

which produces

```
(Pdb) pp total_data
ColumnID         -1            3030096843   3030096845
RespondentCount            2            1            1

[1 rows x 3 columns]
```

When I convert this dataframe into a dictionary (using `total_data.to_dict('records')[0]`), I get

```py
{3030096843: 1, 3030096845: 1, -1: 2}
```

but I want to make sure the 303 columns are cast as strings instead of integers so that I get this:

```py
{'3030096843': 1, '3030096845': 1, -1: 2}
```

Comment: From pandas 1.0, [the documentation recommends using `astype("string")` instead of `astype(str)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html#text-data-types) for some pretty good reasons, take a look.

Answer (score 607, accepted):

One way to convert to string is to use [astype](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
total_rows['ColumnID'] = total_rows['ColumnID'].astype(str)
```

However, perhaps you are looking for the [`to_json`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html) function, which will convert keys to valid json (and therefore your keys to strings):

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame([['A', 2], ['A', 4], ['B', 6]])

In [12]: df.to_json()
Out[12]: '{"0":{"0":"A","1":"A","2":"B"},"1":{"0":2,"1":4,"2":6}}'

In [13]: df[0].to_json()
Out[13]: '{"0":"A","1":"A","2":"B"}'
```

*Note: you can pass in a buffer/file to save this to, along with some other options...*

Comment: I think to_string() is preferable due to the preservation of NULLs http://stackoverflow.com/a/44008334/3647167

Comment: @Keith null preservation is attractive. but the doc says its purpose is to 'Render a DataFrame to a console-friendly tabular output'. i'd like someone authoritative to weigh in

Comment: `to_json()` probably does not call `astype(str)` as it leaves datetime64 and its subclasses as milliseconds since epoch.

Comment: @Sussch I suspect that's because json doesn't have an explicit datetime format, so you're kinda forced to use epoch. Which is to say, I think that's the standard.

Comment: @webNoob13: this is desired/intended behaviour - those are Pandas strings, essentially. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34881079/pandas-distinction-between-str-and-object-types

Comment: @rocksteady hi I'm sorry I read that after I posted something about indefinite length and arranging the array to be contiguous or to save memory blah blah.

Comment: I have done `df.iloc[:,9:].astype(str)` and verified correct columns. But `df.info()` still shows them as int64. Shouldn't they be objects?

Answer (score 149):

If you need to convert ALL columns to strings, you can simply use:

```
df = df.astype(str)
```

This is useful if you need everything except a few columns to be strings/objects, then go back and convert the other ones to whatever you need (integer in this case):

```
 df[["D", "E"]] = df[["D", "E"]].astype(int)
```

Comment: I would prefer your answer - because the OP asked for 'all' columns, not individual columns.

Comment: Doesn't this throw `SettingWithCopyWarning: ` in latest pandas?

Answer (score 94):

### pandas >= 1.0: [It's time to stop using `astype(str)`!](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html#text-data-types)

Prior to pandas 1.0 (well, 0.25 actually) this was the defacto way of declaring a Series/column as as string:

```
# pandas <= 0.25
# Note to pedants: specifying the type is unnecessary since pandas will 
# automagically infer the type as object
s = pd.Series(['a', 'b', 'c'], dtype=str)
s.dtype
# dtype('O')
```

From pandas 1.0 onwards, consider using [**`"string"` type**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.StringDtype.html#pandas.StringDtype) instead.

```
# pandas >= 1.0
s = pd.Series(['a', 'b', 'c'], dtype="string")
s.dtype
# StringDtype
```

Here's why, as quoted by the docs:

> 1. You can accidentally store a mixture of strings and non-strings in an object dtype array. It’s better to have a dedicated dtype.
> 2. `object` dtype breaks dtype-specific operations like `DataFrame.select_dtypes()`. There isn’t a clear way to select just text
>    while excluding non-text but still object-dtype columns.
> 3. When reading code, the contents of an `object` dtype array is less clear than `'string'`.

See also the section on [Behavioral Differences between `"string"` and `object`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html#behavior-differences).

[Extension types](https://pandas.pydata.org/community/blog/extension-arrays.html) (introduced in 0.24 and formalized in 1.0) are closer to pandas than numpy, which is good because numpy types are not powerful enough. For example NumPy does not have any way of representing missing data in integer data (since `type(NaN) == float`). But pandas can using [Nullable Integer columns](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html).

---

#### Why should I stop using it?

##### Accidentally mixing dtypes

The first reason, as outlined in the docs is that you can accidentally store non-text data in object columns.

```
# pandas <= 0.25
pd.Series(['a', 'b', 1.23])   # whoops, this should have been "1.23"

0       a
1       b
2    1.23
dtype: object

pd.Series(['a', 'b', 1.23]).tolist()
# ['a', 'b', 1.23]   # oops, pandas was storing this as float all the time.
```

```
# pandas >= 1.0
pd.Series(['a', 'b', 1.23], dtype="string")

0       a
1       b
2    1.23
dtype: string

pd.Series(['a', 'b', 1.23], dtype="string").tolist()
# ['a', 'b', '1.23']   # it's a string and we just averted some potentially nasty bugs.
```

##### Challenging to differentiate strings and other python objects

Another obvious example example is that it's harder to distinguish between "strings" and "objects". Objects are essentially the blanket type for any type that does not support [vectorizable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1422149/what-is-vectorization) operations.

Consider,

```
# Setup
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'B': [{}, [1, 2, 3], 123]})
df
 
   A          B
0  a         {}
1  b  [1, 2, 3]
2  c        123
```

Upto pandas 0.25, there was virtually no way to distinguish that "A" and "B" do not have the same type of data.

```
# pandas <= 0.25  
df.dtypes

A    object
B    object
dtype: object

df.select_dtypes(object)

   A          B
0  a         {}
1  b  [1, 2, 3]
2  c        123
```

From pandas 1.0, this becomes a lot simpler:

```
# pandas >= 1.0
# Convenience function I call to help illustrate my point.
df = df.convert_dtypes()
df.dtypes

A    string
B    object
dtype: object

df.select_dtypes("string")

   A
0  a
1  b
2  c
```

##### Readability

This is self-explanatory ;-)

---

#### OK, so should I stop using it right now?

...No. As of writing this answer (version 1.1), there **are no performance benefits** but the docs expect future enhancements to significantly improve performance and reduce memory usage for `"string"` columns as opposed to objects. With that said, however, it's never too early to form good habits!

Comment: This works if source is a,b,c and fails if source is 1,2,3 etc.

Comment: @Nages I hope so, it generally doesn't make sense to represent numeric data as text.

Comment: That is right. But some times like it happens if you are trying to solve Kaggle titanic competition where Pclass is represented as 1,2 and 3. Here it should be categorical like string format instead of numeric. To solve this problem str has helped instead of string in that case. Any way thanks it works for characters. Thanks for sharing this documentation details.

Comment: As of version 1.4.3, Pandas "string" dtype is still [considered experimental](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.StringDtype.html#pandas.StringDtype).

Answer (score 33):

Here's the other one, **particularly useful to** **convert the multiple columns to string** instead of just single column:

```
In [76]: import numpy as np
In [77]: import pandas as pd
In [78]: df = pd.DataFrame({
    ...:     'A': [20, 30.0, np.nan],
    ...:     'B': ["a45a", "a3", "b1"],
    ...:     'C': [10, 5, np.nan]})
    ...: 

In [79]: df.dtypes ## Current datatype
Out[79]: 
A    float64
B     object
C    float64
dtype: object

## Multiple columns string conversion
In [80]: df[["A", "C"]] = df[["A", "C"]].astype(str) 

In [81]: df.dtypes ## Updated datatype after string conversion
Out[81]: 
A    object
B    object
C    object
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 24):

There are four ways to convert columns to string

```
1. astype(str)
df['column_name'] = df['column_name'].astype(str)

2. values.astype(str)
df['column_name'] = df['column_name'].values.astype(str)

3. map(str)
df['column_name'] = df['column_name'].map(str)

4. apply(str)
df['column_name'] = df['column_name'].apply(str)
```

Lets see the performance of each type

```
#importing libraries
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import time

#creating four sample dataframes using dummy data
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 1000, size =(10000000, 1)), columns =['A'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 1000, size =(10000000, 1)), columns =['A'])
df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 1000, size =(10000000, 1)), columns =['A'])
df4 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1, 1000, size =(10000000, 1)), columns =['A'])

#applying astype(str)
time1 = time.time()
df1['A'] = df1['A'].astype(str)
print('time taken for astype(str) : ' + str(time.time()-time1) + ' seconds')

#applying values.astype(str)
time2 = time.time()
df2['A'] = df2['A'].values.astype(str)
print('time taken for values.astype(str) : ' + str(time.time()-time2) + ' seconds')

#applying map(str)
time3 = time.time()
df3['A'] = df3['A'].map(str)
print('time taken for map(str) : ' + str(time.time()-time3) + ' seconds')

#applying apply(str)
time4 = time.time()
df4['A'] = df4['A'].apply(str)
print('time taken for apply(str) : ' + str(time.time()-time4) + ' seconds')
```

Output

```
time taken for astype(str): 5.472359895706177 seconds
time taken for values.astype(str): 6.5844292640686035 seconds
time taken for map(str): 2.3686647415161133 seconds
time taken for apply(str): 2.39758563041687 seconds
```

`map(str)` and `apply(str)` are takes less time compare with remaining two techniques

Comment: your results are suspicious. `.astype(str)` should definitely be fastest. use `%timeit` to get more reliable results (gives you the average over many trials). `%timeit` gives me 654ms for `.astype(str)`, 1.4s for `.values.astype(str)`, 2.11s for `.map(str)`, and 1.74s for for `.apply(str)`.

Comment: Even though these tests use wall time (`time.time()`), which isn't precise and shouldn't be used to test performance, it turns out [`timeit` test agrees with these results](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75528571/19123103).

Comment: Huh, I wonder if I had hastily timed a smaller Series. Anyway it's good that you took the time to time it rigorously, plus introducing the faster `map(repr)`.

Comment: You can add `df4['A'] = np.array2string(df4['A'].to_numpy())`. This tested 8x as fast as the fastest answer!

Answer (score 8):

I usually use this one:

```
pd['Column'].map(str)
```

Answer (score 5):

currently i do it like this

```
df_pg['store_id'] = df_pg['store_id'].astype('string')
```

Answer (score 2):

### pandas version: 1.3.5

### Updated answer

`df['colname'] = df['colname'].astype(str)` => this should work by default. But if you create `str` variable like `str = "myString"` before using `astype(str)`, this won't work. In this case, you might want to use the below line.

`df['colname'] = df['colname'].astype('str')`

===========

(Note: incorrect old explanation)

`df['colname'] = df['colname'].astype('str')` => converts dataframe column into a string type

`df['colname'] = df['colname'].astype(str)` => gives an error

Comment: I'm using pandas version 1.4.0 and do not get an error for `astype(str)`

Comment: You're right. it worked for me as well. I tried to do `astype(str)` right after reading the file and it worked. I guess previously it gave me an error because I tried to use `astype(str)` after other operations.

Comment: Okay, I found out why `astype(str)` didn't work for me before. it's because I created `str = "value"` variable before  using `astype(str)`.

Answer (score 2):

##### 1. `.map(repr)` is very fast

If you want to convert values to strings in a column, consider `.map(repr)`. For multiple columns, consider `.applymap(str)`.

```py
df['col_as_str'] = df['col'].map(repr)

# multiple columns
df[['col1', 'col2']] = df[['col1', 'col2']].applymap(str)
# or
df[['col1', 'col2']] = df[['col1', 'col2']].apply(lambda col: col.map(repr))
```

In fact, a `timeit` test shows that `map(repr)` is 3 times faster than `astype(str)` (and is faster than any other method mentioned on this page). Even for multiple columns, this runtime difference still holds. The following is the runtime plot of various methods mentioned here.

[image: perfplot]

`astype(str)` has very little overhead but for larger frames/columns, `map`/`applymap` outperforms it.

---

##### 2. Don't convert to strings in the first place

There's very little reason to convert a numeric column into strings given pandas string methods are not optimized and often get outperformed by vanilla Python string methods. If not numeric, there are dedicated methods for those dtypes. For example, datetime columns should be converted to strings using `pd.Series.dt.strftime()`.

One way numeric->string seems to be used is in a machine learning context where a numeric column needs to be treated as categorical. In that case, instead of converting to strings, consider other dedicated methods such as `pd.get_dummies` or `sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder` or `sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder` to process your data instead.

---

##### 3. Use `rename` to convert column names to specific types

The specific question in the OP is about converting column *names* to strings, which can be done by `rename` method:

```py
df = total_rows.pivot_table(columns=['ColumnID'])
df.rename(columns=str).to_dict('records')
# [{'-1': 2, '3030096843': 1, '3030096845': 1}]
```

---

The code used to produce the above plots:

```py
import numpy as np
from perfplot import plot
plot(
    setup=lambda n: pd.Series(np.random.default_rng().integers(0, 100, size=n)),
    kernels=[lambda s: s.astype(str), lambda s: s.astype("string"), lambda s: s.apply(str), lambda s: s.map(str), lambda s: s.map(repr)],
    labels= ['col.astype(str)', 'col.astype("string")', 'col.apply(str)', 'col.map(str)', 'col.map(repr)'],
    n_range=[2**k for k in range(4, 22)],
    xlabel='Number of rows',
    title='Converting a single column into string dtype',
    equality_check=lambda x,y: np.all(x.eq(y)));
plot(
    setup=lambda n: pd.DataFrame(np.random.default_rng().integers(0, 100, size=(n, 100))),
    kernels=[lambda df: df.astype(str), lambda df: df.astype("string"), lambda df: df.applymap(str), lambda df: df.apply(lambda col: col.map(repr))],
    labels= ['df.astype(str)', 'df.astype("string")', 'df.applymap(str)', 'df.apply(lambda col: col.map(repr))'],
    n_range=[2**k for k in range(4, 18)],
    xlabel='Number of rows in dataframe',
    title='Converting every column of a 100-column dataframe to string dtype',
    equality_check=lambda x,y: np.all(x.eq(y)));
```

Comment: Interesting! I've never seen `Series.map(repr)`, but the timing makes sense: [Why is repr(int) faster than str(int)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45376719/13138364)

Answer (score 0):

Using `.apply()` with a `lambda` conversion function also works in this case:

`total_rows['ColumnID'] = total_rows['ColumnID'].apply(lambda x: str(x))`

For entire dataframes you can use `.applymap()`.
(but in any case probably `.astype()` is faster)