# Why is repr(int) faster than str(int)?

Tags: python, performance, python-internals

I am wondering why `repr(int)` is faster than `str(int)`. With the following code snippet:

```
ROUNDS = 10000

def concat_strings_str():
    return ''.join(map(str, range(ROUNDS)))

def concat_strings_repr():
    return ''.join(map(repr, range(ROUNDS)))

%timeit concat_strings_str()
%timeit concat_strings_repr()
```

I get these timings (python 3.5.2, but very similar results with 2.7.12):

```
 1.9 ms ± 17.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
 1.38 ms ± 9.07 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

If I'm on the right path, [the same function `long_to_decimal_string` is getting called](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/abda8ddd3e4927bda1b58cf60a5d09db186f6ca5/Objects/longobject.c#L4989) below the hood.

Did I get something wrong or what else is going on that I am missing?

---

**update**:
This probably has nothing to with `int`'s `__repr__` or `__str__` methods but with the differences between `repr()` and `str()`, as `int.__str__` and `int.__repr__` are in fact comparably fast:

```
def concat_strings_str():
    return ''.join([one.__str__() for one in range(ROUNDS)])

def concat_strings_repr():
    return ''.join([one.__repr__() for one in range(ROUNDS)])

%timeit concat_strings_str()
%timeit concat_strings_repr()
```

results in:

```
2.02 ms ± 24.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
2.05 ms ± 7.07 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: I have Python 2.7.13 on windows 10 as I see absolutelty no significant difference on my machine. Did you try switching the order and see if it is some sort of system resource affect?

Comment: @gbtimmon the order makes no difference

Comment: I'm able to reliably reproduce on OS X using `python3 -m timeit "''.join(map(repr, range(10000)))"` and the equivalent `str` version or numerous runs. That should eliminate most concerns about caches, etc. But the difference goes away if I get rid of the `join`. `python3 -m timeit "map(str, range(10000))"`

Comment: @RobNapier without the `join` the `repr` (or `str`) does not actually get called.

Comment: @RobNapier in python3 `map` returns an iterator so this doesn't actually do anything - you would need to construct the list, e.g. `python3 -m timeit "list(map(str, range(10000)))"`

Comment: If python2 has both at equivalent speeds, could it be something to do with the unicode strings in py3?

Comment: Weighing in again Python 2.6.6 on CentOS6. Could not reproduce.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Because using `str(obj)` must first go through `type.__call__` then [`str.__new__` (create a new string)](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/typeobject.c#L921) then [`PyObject_Str` (make a string out of the object)](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/unicodeobject.c#L15052) which invokes [`int.__str__`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a66f9c6bb134561a24374f10e8c35417d356ce14/Objects/object.c#L538) and, *finally*, uses the function you linked.

`repr(obj)`, which corresponds to `builtin_repr`, directly calls [`PyObject_Repr` (get the object repr)](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/bltinmodule.c#L2048) which then calls [`int.__repr__`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a66f9c6bb134561a24374f10e8c35417d356ce14/Objects/object.c#L485) which uses the same function as `int.__str__`.

Additionally, the path they take through [`call_function`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/ceval.c#L4824) (the function that handles the [`CALL_FUNCTION` opcode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#opcode-CALL_FUNCTION) that's generated for calls) is *slightly* different.

From the master branch on GitHub (CPython 3.7):

- `str` goes through [`_PyObject_FastCallKeywords`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6969eaf4682beb01bc95eeb14f5ce6c01312e297/Objects/call.c#L136) (which is the one that calls `type.__call__`). Apart from performing more checks, this also needs to create a tuple to hold the positional arguments (see [`_PyStack_AsTuple`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6969eaf4682beb01bc95eeb14f5ce6c01312e297/Objects/call.c#L1270)).
- `repr` goes through [`_PyCFunction_FastCallKeywords`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6969eaf4682beb01bc95eeb14f5ce6c01312e297/Objects/call.c#L717) which calls [`_PyMethodDef_RawFastCallKeywords`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6969eaf4682beb01bc95eeb14f5ce6c01312e297/Objects/call.c#L588). `repr` is also lucky because, since it only accepts a single argument (the switch leads it to the `METH_0` case in `_PyMethodDef_RawFastCallKeywords`) there's no need to create a tuple, just [indexing of the args](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6969eaf4682beb01bc95eeb14f5ce6c01312e297/Objects/call.c#L640).

As your update states, this isn't about `int.__repr__` vs `int.__str__`,  they are the same function after all; it's all about how `repr` and `str` reach them. `str` just needs to work a bit harder.

Answer (score 12):

I just compared the `str` and `repr` implementations in the 3.5 branch.
See [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.5.2/Objects/object.c#L457-L552).

There seems to be more checks in `str`: [image]

Answer (score 8):

There are several possibilities because the CPython functions that are responsible for the [`str`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.5.2/Objects/object.c#L499-L552) and [`repr`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.5.2/Objects/object.c#L457-L497) return are slightly different.

But I guess the primary reason is that `str` is a `type` (a class) and the [`str.__new__`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.5.2/Objects/unicodeobject.c#L14739-L14758) method has to call [`__str__`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.5.2/Objects/unicodeobject.c#L14755) while `repr` can directly go to `__repr__`.