# Why is hexifying strings with % faster than hexifying with f strings?

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, string-formatting, python-3.6

So I have been playing around with f-strings and their speeds in comparison in different scenarios. I ran into a scenario where f strings are slower.

Edit: `x = 0`

```
In[1]: %timeit f"{x:0128x}"
363 ns ± 1.69 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In[2]: %timeit '%0128x' % x
224 ns ± 1.37 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In[3]: %timeit f"{x:0128X}"
533 ns ± 22 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In[4]: %timeit "%0128X" % x
222 ns ± 0.408 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Why are f-strings slower in this scenario, and why is 'X' so much slower than 'x' for f-strings?

Comment: One sidenote: I'm not sure if title should be "hexifying strings" if the original value `x` is an integer.

Comment: Perhaps a better way to state is is "using hexadecimal formatting"

Comment: You can edit the title.

Comment: Why should one be faster or slower? `str.format()` and `f"..."` strings are way more versatile and have more features.

Comment: It's not that I want one to be faster than the other. It's more of just why it's faster. I simply want to understand the scenario and not necessarily vouch that one is faster than the other.

Comment: @xNinjaKittyx: they are different implementations that do different things, so yes, there will be speed differences.

Comment: because one (`f`-strings) is a much more complex operation than the other.

Comment: Note that you should really avoid using different scopes. `% x` uses `x` as a local, `f"..."` may well be looking up `x` as a global. Put both in a function to ensure equal scopes. I then get 430ns and 304ns per loop.

Comment: Show us what `x` is.

Comment: I think the issue that @MartijnPieters is referring to is correct. These are using different scopes hence the huge ns difference. After adding `x=0` at the beginning of the timeit string, it seems to be equal now.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45376719/why-is-reprint-faster-than-strint

Answer (score 2):

String interpolation with `%x` (and other numeric conversions) can't be overloaded, so the interpreter can perform it quickly.

f-strings are the same thing as the `format()` built-in function, which needs to look for a `__format__` method on the object. This is slower.

For instance, this class can override `%s` and `format()`, but can't override `%x`:

```
class myint(int):
    def __format__(self, spec):
        return "example"
    def __int__(self):
        return "example"
    def __str__(self):
        return "example"
    def __repr__(self):
        return "example"
```

```
>>> '%x' % myint()
'0'
```

Capitalizing the string, in the CPython implementation, first builds the lowercase string then loops over the string to change the case.

Overriding `__str__`, even to return a constant string, will also make `%s` slower than `%x`, since it involves a method call.

Comment: Thank you for the insight. I think the biggest problem was how these functions were looking for the original `x` value. Since the test I showed above had x as a prior declaration, it showed the numbers drastically different than setting x as a local variable.