# How to sort numpy array containing string types and np.nan

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am going through a pandas demo and I am trying to sort a numpy array of zip codes as strings, but there is a nan value in the array which is giving me and error when I try np.ndarray.sort().

This is the demo I am following (at in[48]): http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/jvns/pandas-cookbook/blob/v0.2/cookbook/Chapter%207%20-%20Cleaning%20up%20messy%20data.ipynb

Here is example values (these are truncated from the actual demo example)

```
>>>print(unique_zips)
['11432' '11378' '10032' '10023' '10027' '11372' '11419' '11417' '10011'
 nan '10033' '11216' '10016' '10305' '10312' '10026' '10309' '10036']
```

Here is the error

```
>>>print(unique_zips.sort())
TypeError: unorderable types: float() < str()
```

#### Workaround

I found that I could get around this problem by sorted the list beforehand like this:

```
unique_zips = requests['Incident Zip'].sort_values().unique()
print(unique_zips)

out:
['00083', ... '92123', nan]
```

But if I do this I get the error

```
unique_zips = requests['Incident Zip'].unique()
print(unique_zips.sort())

out:
TypeError: unorderable types: float() < str()
```

I checked the type of nan, and it is a 'float' which explains the error float() < str().

My solution is an ok work around, but I would like to understand why the nan in my numpy array is not letting me sort the array. I don't like how I have to sort the values before I call unique(). This may be slower and also not ideal since I want my results to match the demo I am following.

Is there a flag I can set when sorting the numpy array to handle the nan?

Comment: Perhaps coercing to the same type might help. numpy.ndarray.astype or pandas astype, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22005911/convert-columns-to-string-in-pandas

Comment: Why don't you just drop the `nan` values?

Comment: can't you do: `sorted([y for y in unique_zips if str(y) != 'nan'])`

Comment: @YOLO you could, potentially, if you converted to string type. But that's a list comprehension that now drops numpy

Answer (score 0):

This should sort your original array based on the numerical values and ignoring `numpy.nan`.

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array(['11432', '11378', '10032', '10023', '10027', '11372', '11419', 
                '11417', '10011', np.nan, '10033', '11216', '10016', '10305', 
                '10312', '10026', '10309', '10036'])

arr = np.sort(arr[~np.isnan(arr.astype(float))])
```

This should work just fine on Pandas columns (`Series`) too.

The tilda (`~`) negates the condition and filters on where this condition "is not True". But you shouldn't really have arrays of mixed type in the first place; why do you have mostly strings and a `NaN`? None of the vectorized capabilities of NumPy will work on such an array. This particular filter works because each of your strings can be cast to type `float` as a common denominator for your mixed data; the result is still of type string.