# Convert a column of 'int' to 'string'

Tags: python, string, int

I have a test.csv file containing the following data:

```
id   code
1000 60
1001 54
1002 60
1003 28
```

I read in .csv file into python. the columns are all 'int64'. I set 'id' as index, and want to convert the 'code' to string. I used the following code:

```
test = pd.read_csv("test.csv")
test = test.set_index('id')
test['code'] = test.to_string(columns = ['code'])
```

This is what I got in the new dataframe:

```
id   code
1000    code
     id    1000    60
1001    code
     id    1000    60
1002    code
     id    1000    60
1003    code
     id    1000    60
```

What's wrong with my code?

Thank you so much!

Comment: You are calling `.to_string` on the entire data frame, however you would like to only update the `code` column. You can do so like `test['code'] = test.code.astype(str)`

Comment: `df['code'] = df['code'].astype(str);`

`assert isinstance(df['code'][0], str)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Columns to String in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22005911/convert-columns-to-string-in-pandas)

Comment: why don't you pass `dtype={'code':str}` to `read_csv`?