# Cannot convert pandas column to string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a text file containing a column of numbers:

```
10              
20               
40              
13               
24                
35               
44
```

I convert this to a pandas column, and try to convert it to string. But for some reason I can't seem to do so.

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv('file.txt')
df.columns=['column1']
df['column1']=df['column1'].astype(str)
print(df['column1'])
```

This gives:

```
0    10
1    20
2    40
3    13
4    24
5    35
6    44
Name: column1, dtype: object
```

The dtype is still object isntead of string. Don't quite know why this is the case, since astype should convert it to string.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert Columns to String in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22005911/convert-columns-to-string-in-pandas)

Comment: No, since I already knew how to convert it to a string, I was just confused as to the printout and nomenclature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is how `pandas` define the column type , there is not string type column, it belong to `object`

```
df.column1.apply(type)
0    <class 'str'>
1    <class 'str'>
2    <class 'str'>
3    <class 'str'>
4    <class 'str'>
5    <class 'str'>
Name: column1, dtype: object
```

DataFrame dose not `str.replace`

You should do

```
df.replace({'...':'...'})
```

Or

```
df['column1']=df['column1'].str.replace()
```

Comment: The problem is when I try to do ```df['column1']=df.str.replace()```, I get an error ```AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'``` implying the dataframe is still not a string. This is why i was trying to convert it to a string

Comment: @samman that is for series not dataframe , I have update my answer

Comment: So do I even need to change the types to str? To try your method? Also what's the difference between df.replace and df[].str.replace