# Dataframe.to_string() issue

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have  a dataframe with text value and int inside. 
I apply `df.to_string()` without a problem, then I call a the `get_value()` function on it and get rid of the possible space at the beginning and at the end:

```
df.get_value(index,column).rstrip(' ').lstrip(' ')
```

This works fine, however if the value type is int, i got this error :

> AttributeError: 'numpy.int64' object has no attribute 'rstrip'

Why does df.to_string() not work ?

Comment: You can convert to `string` all values of `DataFrame` first - `df = df.astype(str)`

Comment: Maybe duplicated with this one. http://stackoverflow.com/a/17950531/5226708

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you need convert `DataFrame` to `string` by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html), for remove first and last whitespaces is better `strip()`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['  s  ','s','d'],
                   'B':[4,5,6],
                   'C':[7,8,9],
                   'D':[1,3,5],
                   'E':[5,3,6],
                   'F':[7,4,3]})

print (df)
       A  B  C  D  E  F
0    s    4  7  1  5  7
1      s  5  8  3  3  4
2      d  6  9  5  6  3

print (df.astype(str).get_value(0,'A').strip())
s

print (df.astype(str).loc[0,'A'].strip())
s
```