# Pandas: change between mean/std and plus/minus notations

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, string-formatting

Let's assume I have a Pandas's `DataFrame`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(10, 4)), columns=('A', 'DA', 'B', 'DB'))
```

which outputs:

```
    A  DA   B  DB
0  62  87  10  39
1  56   7  81  12
2  37  26  21  44
3  56  26  42  32
4  29  45  11   9
5  11  85   4  79
6  87  31  61  90
7   5  55  26  47
8  55  94  20  84
9  52  26  72  19
```

I would like to convert that to this:

```
       A      B
0  62±87  10±39
1   56±7  81±12
2  37±26  21±44
3  56±26  42±32
4  29±45   11±9
5  11±85   4±79
6  87±31  61±90
7   5±55  26±47
8  55±94  20±84
9  52±26  72±19
```

and **viceversa**.

I could do this "by hand" but I was hoping for an elegant way using Pandas' built-ins, which could eventually be converted elegantly to LaTeX (i.e. `62±87` becomes `$62 \pm 87$`).

I was looking into `.apply()` from [Converting a column within pandas dataframe from int to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17950374/converting-a-column-within-pandas-dataframe-from-int-to-string#17950531) but it is not clear to me how to use it for this purpose.

**EDIT**

The suggested answer do NOT seem to cover the VICEVERSA: i.e. convertin from the `A±DA` notation back to two columns `A` and `DA`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combine two columns of text in dataframe in pandas/python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19377969/combine-two-columns-of-text-in-dataframe-in-pandas-python)

Comment: Thanks for pointing to that, but it does not seem cover going from the `±` notation back to two columns.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's one way

```
In [1336]: (df.groupby(df.columns.str[-1], axis=1)
              .apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).apply('±'.join, 1)))
Out[1336]:
       A      B
0  62±87  10±39
1   56±7  81±12
2  37±26  21±44
3  56±26  42±32
4  29±45   11±9
5  11±85   4±79
6  87±31  61±90
7   5±55  26±47
8  55±94  20±84
9  52±26  72±19
```

Another way

```
In [1351]: pd.DataFrame({c: df.filter(like=c).astype(str).apply('±'.join, 1) 
                         for c in df.columns.str[-1].unique()})
Out[1351]:
       A      B
0  62±87  10±39
1   56±7  81±12
2  37±26  21±44
3  56±26  42±32
4  29±45   11±9
5  11±85   4±79
6  87±31  61±90
7   5±55  26±47
8  55±94  20±84
9  52±26  72±19
```

Or, also as

```
In [1386]: pd.DataFrame({c: ['±'.join(v) for v in df.filter(like='A').astype(str).values]
      ...:               for c in df.columns.str[-1].unique()})
```

---

And, opposite assuming `dff` is your string joined dataframe

```
In [1357]: pd.concat([dff[c].str.split('±', expand=True).rename(columns={0:c, 1:'D'+c})
                      for c in dff.columns], axis=1)
Out[1357]:
    A  DA   B  DB
0  62  87  10  39
1  56   7  81  12
2  37  26  21  44
3  56  26  42  32
4  29  45  11   9
5  11  85   4  79
6  87  31  61  90
7   5  55  26  47
8  55  94  20  84
9  52  26  72  19
```

---

Details

```
In [1358]: df
Out[1358]:
    A  DA   B  DB
0  62  87  10  39
1  56   7  81  12
2  37  26  21  44
3  56  26  42  32
4  29  45  11   9
5  11  85   4  79
6  87  31  61  90
7   5  55  26  47
8  55  94  20  84
9  52  26  72  19

In [1359]: dff
Out[1359]:
       A      B
0  62±87  10±39
1   56±7  81±12
2  37±26  21±44
3  56±26  42±32
4  29±45   11±9
5  11±85   4±79
6  87±31  61±90
7   5±55  26±47
8  55±94  20±84
9  52±26  72±19
```

Helpers

```
In [1377]: df.columns.str[-1]
Out[1377]: Index([u'A', u'A', u'B', u'B'], dtype='object')

In [1378]: df.columns.str[-1].unique()
Out[1378]: Index([u'A', u'B'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: This solves it neatly. If I understood correctly `df.columns.str[-1].unique()` picks up all the columns ending with the different characters. It would be nice to explain that. Eventually "grouping" columns that do not start with `D` or even `Δ` is probably more useful.

Answer (score 2):

A more elegant and scalable way is to **stack, group and combine** separate dataframes with +/- (I like to think of presenting values and errors). The problem in question is a special case.

```py
import pandas as pd

mu = pd.DataFrame({'trace1':[1,2],'trace2':[3,4]}).astype(str)
mu.index.name = 'param'
std = pd.DataFrame({'trace1':[0.01,0.02],'trace2':[0.03,0.04]}).astype(str)
std.index.name = 'param'

pd.concat([mu,std],axis=0).groupby('param').agg(lambda mu_std: '±'.join(mu_std))
```

This example gives

| param | trace1 | trace2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1±0.01 | 3±0.03 |
| 1 | 2±0.02 | 4±0.04 |

Answer (score 1):

Here I found a bunch of them so possible a duplicate: [Combine two columns of text in dataframe in pandas/python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19377969/combine-two-columns-of-text-in-dataframe-in-pandas-python)

This one convinced me the most:

```
import io
import pandas as pd

string = """A,DA,B,DB
62,87,10,39"""

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(string),sep=",")

cols = [i for i in df.columns if len(i) == 1]

for i in cols:
    df[i] = df[i].astype(str)+ "±" + df["D"+i].astype(str)

df[cols]
```

Comment: This does not extend easily to many columns requiring to be combined, though.

Comment: @norok2 that wasn't the original question, but yes.. you had a point, however with some small modifications I made it work. Keep it simple I'd say :). The solution above works too ofc.