# pandas convert numbers to words in every rows and one specific column

Tags: regex, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, replace

UPDATE

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
df.iloc[:,3].replace(r'(?<!\S)\d+(?!\S)', lambda x: p.number_to_words(x.group()), regex=True, inplace=True)
df.iloc[:,3].head(2)
0    15
1    89
Name: D, dtype: int64

df = df.astype(str)
df.iloc[:,3].replace(r'(?<!\S)\d+(?!\S)', lambda x: p.number_to_words(x.group()), regex=True, inplace=True)

df.iloc[:,3].head(2)
0    <function <lambda> at 0x7fd8a6b4db18>
1    <function <lambda> at 0x7fd8a6b4db18>
Name: D, dtype: object
```

I got a pandas data frame and some of the rows contains numbers in some columns. I want to use the inflect library to replace only the numbers with corresponding word representation.

I think df.replace is a good fit.  But how can I specify that only numbers 
 (all the numbers which are separated by white spaces) should be replaced and pass it as argument to inflect ?.

```
p = inflect.engine()
df.replace(r' (\d+) ', p.number_to_words($1), regex=True, inplace=True)
```

Similarly, I have second dataframe, where I want to do it for a specific column, column with index 4. The column contains just 4 digit numbers only (year). How can I do it ?.

Comment: Try `df.replace(r'(?<!\S)\d+(?!\S)', lambda x: p.number_to_words(x.group()), regex=True, inplace=True)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it can not be used if i want to replace in a column which contains just numbers (for example my forth column contains years, and I want to replace it with words)

Comment: Do you mean you have `int`s? Then try [casting them to string, `.astype(str)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17950374/converting-a-column-within-pandas-dataframe-from-int-to-string).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I want to convert it to equivalent words not just data type conversion.  I want 1974 to be replaced by one thousand seventy four.  I tried    df.iloc[:,3].replace(r'(?=\^)\d+(?=\$)', lambda x: p.number_to_words(x.group()), regex=True, inplace=True)

Comment: `r'(?=\^)\d+(?=\$)'` is wrong. It must be `r'(?<!\S)\d+(?!\S)'`. What I mean, regex only works with strings, so you need to pass a string to the `re.sub` that is used behind the scenes.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew. Oh Ok got it.  Updated the question also

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  Now I get some thing like this <function <lambda> at 0x7fd8a6b4db18>   instead of the words.

Comment: Try `df.iloc[:,3].astype(str).apply(lambda row: re.sub(r'(?<!\S)\d+(?!\S)', lambda x: p.number_to_words(x.group()), row))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import `re` library, make sure your column is of type `string`, and use `(?<!\S)\d+(?!\S)` to match sequences of digits that are between start/end of string and whitespace chars. If you want to only match whole entries that are all digits, you may use `^\d+$` regex.

```
df.iloc[:,3].astype(str).apply(lambda row: re.sub(r'(?<!\S)\d+(?!\S)', lambda x: p.number_to_words(x.group()), row))
```

First, the column is cast to string with `.astype(str)`. Then, `(?<!\S)\d+(?!\S)` matches in each `row` and the number is sent to the `.number_to_words()` method.