# pandas: Convert int Series to new StringDtype

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to convert an `UInt8` pandas series into the new `StringDtype`.

I can do the following, covered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17950374/converting-a-column-within-pandas-dataframe-from-int-to-string), which predates the new `string` dtype:

```py
import pandas as pd
int_series = pd.Series(range(20), dtype="UInt8")
obj_series = int_series.apply(str)
```

Which gives me a series of Object dtype containing strings.

But if I try to convert the series to the new `string` dtype, I get an error:

```py
>>> string_series = int_series.astype("string")
...
TypeError: data type not understood
```

Note that the first converting the series to `Object` and then to `string` dtype works:

```py
int_series.apply(str).astype("string")
```

How can I convert the int series to string directly?

I'm using pandas version 1.0.3 on Python 3.7.6

---

**Update:** I've found [this open issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/31204) in the pandas Github page that describes the exact same problem.

A comment in the issue above points to [another open issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/22384) which covers the desired but currently not available functionality of converting between different ExtensionArray types.

So the answer is that the direct conversion cannot be done now, but likely will be possible in the future.

Comment: I always thought that `pandas` only has `object` as dtype for string values. Interesting.

Comment: according to [this doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html), `int_series.astype('string')` should work, yet it doesn't.

Comment: @QuangHoang: Yes, the `string` dtype is new in version 1.0.0

Comment: If you don't use "UInt8" but regular int, the error is more explicit: `ValueError: StringArray requires a sequence of strings or pandas.NA`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is explained in the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.arrays.StringArray.html#pandas.arrays.StringArray), in the example section:

> Unlike object dtype arrays, StringArray **doesn’t allow non-string values**

Where the following example is shown:

> `pd.array(['1', 1], dtype="string")`
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   ...
>   ValueError: StringArray requires an object-dtype ndarray of strings.

The only solution seems to be casting to `Object` dtype as you were doing and *then*  to string.

This is also clearly stated in the [source code of `StringArray`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.0.3/pandas/core/arrays/string_.py#L86-L319), where right at the top you'll see the warning:

> ```
>    .. warning::
>        Currently, this expects an object-dtype ndarray
>        where the elements are Python strings or :attr:`pandas.NA`.
>        This may change without warning in the future. Use
>        :meth:`pandas.array` with ``dtype="string"`` for a stable way of
>        creating a `StringArray` from any sequence.
> ```

If you check the validation step in `_validate`, you'll see how this will fail for arrays of non-strings:

```
def _validate(self):
    """Validate that we only store NA or strings."""
    if len(self._ndarray) and not lib.is_string_array(self._ndarray, skipna=True):
        raise ValueError("StringArray requires a sequence of strings or pandas.NA")
    if self._ndarray.dtype != "object":
        raise ValueError(
            "StringArray requires a sequence of strings or pandas.NA. Got "
            f"'{self._ndarray.dtype}' dtype instead."
        )
```

For the example in the question:

```
from pandas._libs import lib

lib.is_string_array(np.array(range(20)), skipna=True)
# False
```

Comment: I understand this point for array creation, not conversion. This `pd.array([1, "2"], dtype="UInt8")` fails but this succeeds `pd.array([1, "2"], dtype="object").astype("UInt8")`. So although `UInt8` does not accept a string, it can still convert a string using `astype`

Comment: Yes, because previously you've casted to object. And afaik casting to another dtype with `astype` is the same as creating a dataframe or series anew, note that it creates a copy @foglerit

Comment: It seems there's a bug. The warning you quote is for the `values` parameter for the `StringArray` `__init__` method. It states that this should work `pd.array(int_series, dtype="string")` but it does not.

Comment: In any case, you answer is very insightful. I'll open an issue in Github and accept your answer when they confirm your point.

Comment: Where is this stated? The warning seems quite clear in that non-string values cannot be directly converted @foglerit

Comment: You may be right. I interpreted the statement: Use `:meth:pandas.array` with `dtype="string"` for a stable way of creating a `StringArray` from *any* sequence as in opposition to using the class constructor, and that the "any array" implied the ability to convert types.