# Why isn't my column converting to string from int?

Tags: python, pandas, string, integer

```
*Input:*
df["waiting_time"].value_counts()
​
*Output:*
2 days      6724
4 days      5290
1 days      5213
7 days      4906
6 days      4037
            ... 
132 days       1
125 days       1
117 days       1
146 days       1
123 days       1
Name: waiting_time, Length: 128, dtype: int64
```

I tried:

df['wait_dur'] = df['waiting_time'].values.astype(str)

and I've tried apply as well. No changes to the data type, it stays the same.

Answer (score 2):

You need to skip the 'values' part in your code:

```
    df['wait_dur'] = df['waiting_time'].astype(str)
```

If you check first row for example, you will get:

```
    type(df['wait_dur'][0])
    <class 'str'>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df = df.applymap(str)
```

This should work, it applies the `map` `string` throughout.

If you want to see more methods go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17950374/converting-a-column-within-pandas-dataframe-from-int-to-string).