# Why is this returning an empty list? Using df.isin to filter my df object

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list with certificate numbers:

`prod_cmvp_data = ['3914', '3907', '3197', '4272', '4271', '4254', '3784', '3946', '3888', '4174', '4222', '3613', '3125', '3140', '3197', '3196', '3644', '3615', '3651', '3918', '3946', '4271', '3888', '4174', '4222', '3613', '3125', '3140']`

I also have a df object and one of the columns is "Certificate_Number". My goal is to iterate through it and only return the rows where the "Certificate_Number" matches with the certificate numbers from the list `prod_cmvp_data`

Here's my code:

```
def main():
    certs_url = "https://csrc.nist.gov/projects/cryptographic-module-validation-program/validated-modules/search/all"
    

    prod_cmvp_data = get_prod_cmvp_data()
    data = get_html(certs_url)
    cmvp_data = get_cmvp_data(data, prod_cmvp_data)
    sunset_date(cmvp_data, prod_cmvp_data)
    write_file('txt', cmvp_data)


def get_prod_cmvp_data():
    # parse excel sheet for client CMVP data and remove empty cells
    prod_cmvp_data = pd.read_excel('_Request ID__Client Cryptographic Module List Template.xlsx', header = 4)
    drop_na = prod_cmvp_data.dropna(subset=['CMVP #'])
    # convert df obj to list
    to_list = drop_na['CMVP #'].values.tolist()
    # remove '#' and blank spaces from list values - only CMVP numbers remain
    rmv_excess_chars = [item.strip('# ') for item in to_list]   
    return rmv_excess_chars

def get_html(url):
    # make request to URL and convert to BS obj
    req = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')
    return soup


def get_cmvp_data(cmvp_content, prod_data):
    # --- Build CMVP dataframe ---
    search_tbl = cmvp_content.find_all('table', id='searchResultsTable')
    # convert HTML table to df obj
    cert_table = pd.read_html(str(search_tbl))
    df = cert_table[0]
    # print(df)
    # column headers - sub spaces w/'_'
    df.columns = [column.replace(" ", "_") for column in df.columns]
    # print(df.columns)
    df_new = df[df['Certificate_Number'].isin(prod_data)]
    

        # sort data - vendor name descending
    # df_filtered = df_filtered.sort_values(by=['Vendor_Name', 'Certificate_Number'], ascending=True)


    return df_new

def sunset_date(cmvp_data, prod_cmvp_data):
    condensed_cmvp_data = cmvp_data.get(["Certificate_Number", "Validation_Date"])


    print(prod_cmvp_data)
    print(cmvp_data)
```

Running this will give me this output:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Certificate_Number, Vendor_Name, Module_Name, Module_Type, Validation_Date]
Index: []
```

For context, if I run `print(df)` this is what the df object is:

```
 Certificate Number                         Vendor Name                                        Module Name Module Type                                    Validation Date
0                  4293         Qualcomm Technologies, Inc.                   Qualcomm® Secure Processing Unit    Hardware                                         09/06/2022
1                  4292                      Canonical Ltd.          Ubuntu 20.04 OpenSSL Cryptographic Module    Software                                         09/06/2022
2                  4291              Extreme Networks, Inc.    Extreme Networks SLX 9540 and SLX 9740 Switches    Hardware                                         09/01/2022
3                  4290                           LogRhythm               LogRhythm 7.8.0 System Monitor Agent    Software                                         08/31/2022
4                  4289                           LogRhythm                   LogRhythm 7.8.0 Platform Manager    Software                                         08/31/2022
..                  ...                                 ...                                                ...         ...                                                ...
816                1938                      SafeLogic Inc.                            CryptoComply for Mobile    Software  04/30/201311/08/201304/23/201401/25/201602/10/...
817                1592         L3Harris Technologies, Inc.                          Harris Unified Audio Card    Hardware           08/22/201104/13/201607/20/201808/30/2021
818                1363             Progress Software, Inc.                                      MOVEit Crypto    Software  07/12/201004/26/201604/27/201601/24/201801/30/...
819                1324  Comtech Mobile Datacom Corporation             Transceiver Cryptographic Module (TCM)    Hardware           07/12/201004/18/201605/08/201810/16/2020
820                 911         L3Harris Technologies, Inc.  Harris Corporation Wireless Systems Cryptograp...    Software  02/07/200807/02/201004/10/201504/27/201603/01/...
```

I want to iterate through my df object and only return the rows that contain one of the certificate numbers from my `prod_cmvp_data` list. I know it only shows a few of the items in my df object, but the first number in my list '3914' is also in my df object, along with many of those other numbers. None of them are being returned and instead, it's just returning an empty list.

Comment: What dtype is the Certificate Number column? ... `print(df.dtypes)`. - number or string/object?

Comment: Most of the code in your example does not seem relavent to your problem can you reduce it to a [mre]?

Comment: I'd bet `df['Certificate_Number']` is numeric type (int?).

Comment: @wwii it says dtype for that column is int64

Comment: @QuangHoang I just checked and it's type int64

Comment: That's your problem, your data is `int64`, but lookup list, i.e. `prod_cmvp_data` is string type. You should make them either both `int` or both `str`.

Comment: @QuangHoang is there a way to convert it from int to str using pandas?

Comment: `df['Certificate_Number'].astype(str)`?

Comment: Does [Converting a column within pandas dataframe from int to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17950374/converting-a-column-within-pandas-dataframe-from-int-to-string) answer your question?

Comment: @wwii Once I converted them both to string it worked, them being different data types was the issue